# I want My form button to appear in one single line with other buttons

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have designed a table using bootstrap 4 but the problem is my form button appears on next line, but I want to appear it in one single line with the other buttons.
I want it to appear just after the "Delete" Button.

I also want that when I click on approve it will save approved keyword in MySQL table.

Code:

```
<td>
    <div class="d-inline">
        <%=rs.getString(4)%>
        &nbsp;
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="" role="button">Edit</a>
        &nbsp;
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="" role="button">Delete</a>
        <!--&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger" href="../src/java/Login.java" role="button">Approve</a>-->
        <form method="post" action="" class="d-inline">                       
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
        </form>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: @azro edited your post so that the code is readable, and you have just reversed all his efforts, rendering your code completely unreadable and uninterpretable.

Comment: Don't start a rollack war please ;) let the post readable

Comment: What does this have to do with `java`? You are asking for help with your HTML layout, no?

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy for you if you use flex. Use `.d-flex` class for show everything in a row. By default flex direction is row.

```
<td>
<div class="d-inline d-flex">
    <%=rs.getString(4)%>
    &nbsp;
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="" role="button">Edit</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="" role="button">Delete</a>
    <!--&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger" href="../src/java/Login.java" role="button">Approve</a>-->
    <form method="post" action="" class="d-inline">                       
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
    </form>
</div>
```